# is there any possibility that this is not immutable

Tags: c#, thread-safety

```
public class LogMessage
{
    public LogMessage(string message, bool isError)
    {
        Message = message;
        IsError = isError;
    }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public bool IsError { get; private set; }
}
```

Consider above code. Is there any case where the class could not be a completely immutable object? if not, why so?

Comment: It could be changed with System.Reflection

Answer (score 3):

You can modify that class using reflection (or unverifiable IL). Not in a low-trust environment.

This is a good pattern for creating immutable object. I'd like that class.

I don't know whether the .NET memory model is strong enough so that if you hand over that object to another thread it always sees it in an initialized state. It might see the fields uninitialized. On x86 this is impossible anyway because stores act as a barrier and you need at least one store to publish an object.

Comment: what is mutable object and immutable? please add that as well

Comment: what you mean you don't know ??

Comment: I don't understand your question. Maybe a language problem. You mean "What is an immutable object?"? That's out of scope for this question. I suggest you just research that.

Comment: i am just asking what is mutable and immutable as i don't have its idea

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I can't believe you have 8k rep and you are asking such a question in the *comments* section. There's plenty of information available on the internet on mutability and immutability, and if that doesn't satisfy you, then *ask a question*.

Comment: so does 8k reputation means that i know every thing of c#?? as question was related to it so i said that if he could add it in answer as well..:)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I used to think 8k reputation meant you knew how to use the site.

Comment: ohh,,ok sorry i know how to use but as i said it was related to it so i requested to add it if possible well i am researching on it my self as well

Comment: got it what it means..:)

Comment: Why would you want someone answering a question about immutability when the OP clearly knows what immutable/mutable means to then explain what mutability is?